# OSX Sound Output vs Communication Device

Tags: macos

Windows sound options allow me to have two different devices configured: a default output device (my speakers) and a default communication device (my headset). This was great, because I could be listening to music on my speakers, and when I got a call in Gmail, it would automatically mute the speakers and use the headset for the call (input and output).

On my new Macbook, if I'm using the speakers and a Gmail call comes in, it makes me use the speakers and Macbook mic to make the call. And if I try to switch the settings after it starts ringing but before I answer, it still comes out of the speakers.

Is there a way to emulate my setup from Windows in OSX?